# No more E1101, aka "no-member" after pylint upgrade

Tags: python, pylint

Previously on pylint 1.3.1 and astroid 1.2.1 I was getting E1101 or "no-member" errors on my:

```
self.nonExistentMethod()
```

Now after upgrading to pylint 1.6.4 and astroid 1.4.8 I'm no longer getting the error!  It's clearly non-existent (I know it is because in the real case, it is spelled incorrectly).

Any ideas what's changed?

Comment: Are you using latest pylint and astroid versions? If so, you should submit an issue to [Pylint's Github](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues) after searching for an already existing  issue describing the same problem.